# Evento não funciona após executar replaceWith

Tags: jquery

Eu uso esse plugin: http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/

Segue JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oq0zcn94/79/

Após de clicar no botão "replaceWith", o botão "Confirmação" não funciona mais.

Segue código:

```
$('#teste').confirmation();

$("#replaceWith").click(function() {
  $('#teste').replaceWith('<button id="teste">Confirmação</button>');
});
```

O botão "Confirmação" não funciona após de clicar no botão "replaceWith".

Update **@RicardoPontual**:

Segue código:

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation-document]').confirmation({
    singleton: true,
    popout: true,
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation-document]',
    title: '',
    content: '',
    buttons: [
        {
            label: 'Criar',
            onClick: function () {
                //códigos
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Apagar',
            onClick: function () {
                //códigos
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: É poque o DOM já foi carregado. Coloca o script dentro do replaceWith que deve funcionar

Comment: Como o amigo disse, o dom já foi carregado, o listener ouvia o botão antigo e ao trocá-lo, o mesmo se perde. Usa um outro elemento ao invés do botão diretamente: $("body").on("click", "#replaceWith", function(){...})

Comment: [Atualizei o fiddle aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/oq0zcn94/94/) para setar o confirmation com as propriedades, assim fica bom?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, sim. Obrigado por me ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, você substituiu o conteúdo e perdeu o evento, basta adicionar novamente o evento:

```
var ops = { ... };
$( "#replaceWith" ).click(function() {
   $('#teste').replaceWith('<button id="teste">Confirmação</button>');
   $('#teste').confirmation(ops);
});
```

Aqui o fiddle atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/oq0zcn94/94/

Comment: Ricardo, não existe outra forma usando `.on()` do JQuery ?

Comment: Porque eu inicializo assim: `$('#teste').confirmation({ opões e lógica aqui });`

Comment: Não queria copiar todas as opções e lógica novamente.

Comment: Para isso teria de ver o código do método `confirmation()`. O `.on()` serve para eventos suportados, como click e blur. Funcionaria que fosse o evento click do elemento "#replaceWith". Mas você pode colocar as opções numa variável e reutilizar, não ajuda a diminuir a duplicidade?

Comment: Ricardo eu atualizei post, favor olhar código.

Answer (score 2):

O código está um pouco confuso no seu Fiddle, mas o que eu pude perceber é que o replace "mata" toda a configuração feita para o `button id="teste"`

Eu fiz uma pequena alteração:

```
$( "#replaceWith" ).click(function() {
$('#teste').replaceWith('<button id="teste">Confirmação</button>');
$('#teste').confirmation();
});
$('#teste').confirmation();
```

e funciona, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/jxcbp2wz/

Não depurei o JQuery para saber o que é feito em termos de associação de eventos após o `replaceWith`, mas creio que seja relacionado à isso: [Events not registering after replaceWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770308/events-not-registering-after-replacewith)

Comment: Alterei o link do fiddle. Eu copei o link do fiddle original por engano.

Comment: Não existe outra forma, tipo `.on()` ? Porque `$('#teste').confirmation({ varias opções });` dentro de uma função `confirmation`, tem várias opções e grande lógica.